QQmlComponent: Component is not ready - module "QtCharts" is not installed
I am trying to render the QtCharts example on the main page:
import QtCharts

...

        ChartView {
            title: "Line Chart"
            anchors.fill: parent
            antialiasing: true

            LineSeries {
                name: "Line"
                XYPoint {
                    x: 0
                    y: 0
                }
                ...
            }
        }

I have QtCharts and QQmlCharts on the machine (Ubuntu 24.04 - everything installed with apt):
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6ChartsQml.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Charts.so.6.4.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6ChartsQml.so.6.4.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6ChartsQml.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Charts.so

But when I run my c++/qml application or when I just execute the qml code I get:
$ qml qml/HardwareTestScreen.qml
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///home/guido/codes/application/qml/HardwareTestScreen.qml:1:1: module "QtCharts" is not installed
qml: Did not load any objects, exiting.

In the machine I have also compiled and run successfully an application that uses QtCharts but with QtWidgets (w/o Qml). It works well.

Does example app compile? Also QtChart, at least in Qt5, relies on an instance of QAppliction.

yes, it compiles well. I have also included and an run the QApplication instance.

Installing every qml6 module on Ubuntu 24.04 as this answer suggested, fixed the issue. Even though, I don't know which exact package of the whole list fixed it:

sudo apt install qml6-module-*


You have to add the Charts package in your CMAKE file:
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Charts)
target_link_libraries(mytarget PRIVATE Qt6::Charts)


Done already:
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick Concurrent Charts ChartsQml) target_link_libraries(app     PRIVATE Qt6::Quick Qt6::Concurrent Qt6::Charts Qt6::ChartsQml)

what is Qt6::ChartsQml? there is no such module as I know
